# Error encountered while processing debian mongo packages

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I uninstalled mongo from my ubuntu and tried to install it again but getting below error now

```
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.2.7_amd64.deb
     /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.7_amd64.deb
     /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_4.2.7_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I follwed below mentioned link to install mongo again-
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can force the installation package and resume it again.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_4.2.7_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install -f
```